# Changing mysql_connect to mysqli causes function to fail

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

To begin with, I am a novice when it comes to **PHP** and **MySQL**.

I have a **MySQL** table called `levels` that contains two columns: `level_id` and `mapData`. Some time ago, I wrote a piece of code using `mysql_connect` that takes user inputted `level_id` and fetches the corresponding `mapData` from the table, and the code works as intended. See below:

```
<?php
$mysql_host = 'localhost';
$mysql_user = 'username';
$mysql_password = "password";
$mysql_database = 'database';

if (!mysql_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password)||!mysql_select_db($mysql_database)){
 die('Connection failed');
}

function get_map_data($level_id,$field){
$query = "SELECT $field FROM levels WHERE level_id='$level_id'";
    if($query_run = mysql_query($query)){
        if($query_result = mysql_result($query_run,0,$field)){
            return $query_result;
        }
    }
}

$user_input = mysql_real_escape_string(base64_decode($_GET["level_id"]));

$sql = "SELECT level_id FROM levels WHERE level_id='$user_input'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) >0){

$mapData = get_map_data($user_input,'mapData');

print $mapData;

}else{
    echo "0";
}

?>
```

In the case that the user inputs a `level_id` that does not exist in the database, instead of `mapData`, he will receive `0`. Everything works! I, however, read that `mysql_connect` is deprecated as of **PHP 5.5** and decided to switch from using it in my file to using mysqli:

```
$conn = new mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . $conn->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

After changing to `mysqli`, my `get_map_data` function has stopped working. I have made certain that the mysqli connection works, but I am simply hitting my head against the wall in making my function work using it. How do I fix my `get_map_data` function so that it functions again using mysqli?

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix `mysqli` and `mysql_` functions. Furthermore, your `mysqli` initialization is creating an `object`, not a `resource`. Lastly, there is no `mysqli_result()` function, so therefore we need to emulate what you're trying to do. You wanted the first row `0` and then wanted a specific `$field`. Below should be what you want.

```
function get_map_data($level_id,$field){
    $query = "SELECT $field FROM levels WHERE level_id='$level_id'";
    if($query_run = $mysqli->query($query)){
        //no mysqli->result() function, so we need to seek to the row.
        $query_run->data_seek(0);
        if($query_result = $query_run->fetch_assoc()){
            return $query_result[$field];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your get_map_data function currently has query running using mysql_query you have to change that to mysqli_query in order to execute:

```
function get_map_data($level_id,$field){
  $query = "SELECT $field FROM levels WHERE level_id='$level_id'";
if($query_run = mysqli_query($conn,$query)){
    if($query_result = mysqli_result($query_run,0,$field)){
        return $query_result;
    }
}
```

}